# Jenkinsfile copy variable to file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to copy the contents of a variable into a file as part of my pipeline build, I am unable to access the variable it seems

This example will work

```
stage('Copy Var') {
  sh 'echo "This is my string" >> /path/to/file'
  string = sh(script: 'cat /path/to/file', returnStdout: true)
  echo "string is ${string}"
}

// outputs: "string is This is my string"
```

However as soon as i start to use a variable then i get nothing returned

```
string = sh(script: 'cat /path/to/test.txt', returnStdout: true)
stage('Copy Var') {
  sh 'echo "${string}" >> /path/to/file'
  echo "${string}"
  // outputs: test txt
  copy_string = sh(script: 'cat /path/to/file', returnStdout: true)
  echo "string is ${copy_string}"
}
// outputs string is
```

Is there something i am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing the [`readFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-readfile-code-read-file-from-workspace) step:

```
copy_string = readFile('/path/to/file')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, Im just curious as to why this would behave differently when `string = sh(script: 'cat /path/to/test.txt', returnStdout: true)` for example returns a string value

Comment: @Richlewis The result would be exactly the same, right. IIRC, Jenkins can the `readFile` step without allocating a node (which might be helpful in some situations). Further, I prefer to use the means of the DSL instead of always shelling out.